# Trying to change a value mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very new to MySQL database but I have some PHP knowledge
I want to update a value for all `wp_s2member_login couter` field in a table.
I am getting this error when I try to update the table:

> Connected successfully Unknown column 'wp_s2member_login_counter' in 'where clause'

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect('mywebsite.com', 'wrd6rEDgggy', 'mypassword'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(wrd_47io4f3a6l);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE          wp_s2member_login_counter<>'0'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: does the column name match that in the database?

Comment: Forgive me for pointing out the obvious but... Do you have a `wp_s2member_login_counter` column?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Here is a link showing a picture of the table on myphpadmin

Comment: it is saying that  there is no column  named as "wp_s2member_login_counter" in table wp_usermeta. Check column name, via executeing select * from wp_usermeta limit 5

Comment: sorry here it is, www dot freeimagehosting dot net/n2688

Comment: @Lisa Could you please tell me what happens if you type: desc wp_s2member_login_counter

Comment: wp_s2member_login_counter is not column name, column name is meta_key.

Comment: but judging from your query,you probably want meta_value.

Comment: i think this is what you actually want UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE meta_key != '0'

Comment: @Lisa can you list what do you see when you do: desc wp_usermeta

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted above, is your `wp_s2member_login couter` Table supposed to be be `wp_s2member_login counter`?

With the "n" in counter?

Comment: I'm guessing this was downvoted because it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: He can't add comment because of his reputaion

Comment: What will be the proper code to change that value for all wp_s2member_login counter fields?

Comment: All I want to do is set the value to 0 for all fields named "wp_s2member_login counter" in the table.

Comment: UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE meta_key = 'wp_s2member_login_counter'; ?

Comment: Vinit,I believe this is a field that belongs to meta_key column

Comment: does my query do what you wants? set meta_value to all field that have wp_s2member_login_counter as meta_key value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE          wp_s2member_login_counter<'0' OR wp_s2member_login_counter>0")
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='0' WHERE          wp_s2member_login_counter != 0")
```